# Auto-Close AJAX inserted bootstrap alert messages?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time getting bootstrap alert messages to auto-close.

**Alert UI**

```
<div class="alert-message fade in info " runat="server" id="AlertMessage">
    <div class="box-icon"></div>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label>
        <a href="#" class="close" >&times;</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**VB Code-Behind**

```
 lblmsg.Text = Message
 AlertMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "alert-message fade in info")
 RadAjaxPanel_alerts.ResponseScripts.Add(String.Format("$find('{0}').ajaxRequest();", RadAjaxPanel_alerts.ClientID))
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".close").click(function () { 
        $(".alert-message").alert('close'); 
    }); 
});
$(".alert-message").delay(5000).fadeTo(900, 0).slideUp(500, function () { 
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

You can see that when a page requests an alert is shown the AJAX panel is updated. However unless its a full page reload the panel will not auto-close. My assumption is that the JS ran and did not find the div since it was not in the dom at the time. I can't quite figure the rest out.

**JavaScript Inside Update Panel**
Placing the javascript inside the update panel will cause it to be triggered when the update panel is triggered. This induces a new issue. If the page is postback then the DIV will be shown, then the .AjaxRequest(); will call, causing the DIV to be shown again.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Maybe you need to not close the .ready() function just yet.  You need to include the second line of javascript within the .ready() function.  Try it and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$(".alert-message").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: Yes that code will work, but the same issue is still present. If the alert is hidden and then displayed due to a partial page postback within an update panel, that java script will not fire. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this $.ajaxSetup({async:true}); in script code. Or try to add $('action_element').unbind();